# Change values of multiple columns based on the value of one column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data table, `dt1`:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
names = c("A1", "XX", "A2", "XY", "A3", "XZ"),
   A1 = c( 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0), 
   A2 = c( 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0), 
   A3 = c( 0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0)
)
```

I want the new data table like:

```
dt2 <- data.table(
names = c("A1", "XX", "A2", "XY", "A3", "XZ"),
   A1 = c( 1,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0), 
   A2 = c( 0,    0,    1,    0,    0,    0), 
   A3 = c( 0,    0,    0,    0,    1,    0)
)
```

i.e, if the row value of the column `names` is the same as the names of certain column, then the row value of that column is changed to `1`.

I can achieve this via the following code:

```
dt1[names == "A1", "A1" := 1]
dt1[names == "A2", "A2" := 1]
dt1[names == "A3", "A3" := 1]
```

But I'm wondering whether there is an easier way to do this, especially when the number of columns I want to change is big.

I've tried the following lines, and they are not worked:

```
cln <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
dt1[names == (cln), (cln) := 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the efficient `for(...) set(...)` combination of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
for(j in names(dt1)[-1]) {
  set(dt1, dt1[, .I[names == j]], j, value = 1)
}
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dt1
>    names A1 A2 A3
> 1:    A1  1  0  0
> 2:    XX  0  0  0
> 3:    A2  0  1  0
> 4:    XY  0  0  0
> 5:    A3  0  0  1
> 6:    XZ  0  0  0
> ```

Instead of `names(dt1)[-1]` you can also use `setdiff(names(dt1), "names")`.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: @LikanZhan no problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a loop.

```
for(i in colnames(dt1)[-1]) {
 dt1[,i] <- ifelse(dt1[,"names"] == i, 1, 0)
}
```

Comment: `colnames(dt1)[-"names"]` does not work .... (it is not valid R syntax)